# establishing a congruence relationship

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the following deduction correct?
$$ (a+b)\bmod20=y $$
$$\implies (a+b)\bmod20 = y \bmod20$$
$$\implies (a+b) \equiv y\pmod{20}$$

Comment: Yes, that is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When viewing $\bmod{n}$ as a *relation*, we are using the definition that $a \equiv b \pmod{n}\,$ means $n \mid b-a$. In this context, I don't think you would normally see that first statement at all, and if you did, it would just be an awkward way of writing the third statement.

It is also possible to view $\bmod{n}$ as an *operation*, in which case $x \bmod n$ is defined to be the remainder $r$ when $x$ is divided by $n$.

You seem to be using both of these interpretations simultaneously. If you are trying to prove this, I would use the definitions that you are given. If you are going to consider the step from the first to the second equation valid (as in, not needing further explanation), then I don't see that jumping straight from the first to the third would be a problem.

In other words, I would say that either this deduction is trivial enough not to need justification, or else if you are needing to write a proof for some reason, you should use the definitions of the two uses of $\bmod{n}$ and include more detail.

Comment: The first paragraph is incorrect. Mathematicians most certainly do use the binary *operation* $\bmod$

Comment: I think it impolite (and harmful) to denigrate computational mathematics as "applied". Anyone who does any nontrivial computations in number theory and algebra will find need for normal-form operaions. We are (thankfully) long past the old days where computation was frowned upon by many.

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't intend to denigrate it. My research in finite geometry relies heavily on computational algebra and combinatorics (including widespread use of "mod" as an operator). We are perhaps far enough past those days that it did not occur to me that my comment would be taken as looking down on this area of math. I have removed any commentary on where these two viewpoints are likely to occur, to focus simply on the two definitions and how to reconcile them.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, why is the first statement an awkward way of writing the third statement?

Answer (score -1):

It is correct because we can conclude $\ 0\le x<20\ $ from the first line, so $x$ must coincide with $x\mod 20$. The second implication is obvious.